# MonoTouch convert color UIImage with alpha to grayscale and blur?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, grayscale, cgrect

I am trying to find a recipe for producing a a blurred grayscale `UIImage` from a color PNG and alpha.  There are recipes out there in ObjC but MonoTouch does not bind the `CGRect` functions so not sure how to do this.  Any ideas?

Here is one ObjC example of grayscale:

```
(UIImage *)convertImageToGrayScale:(UIImage *)image
{
  // Create image rectangle with current image width/height
  CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

  // Grayscale color space
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();

  // Create bitmap content with current image size and grayscale colorspace
  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, image.size.width, image.size.height, 8, 0,   colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

  // Draw image into current context, with specified rectangle
  // using previously defined context (with grayscale colorspace)
  CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, [image CGImage]);

  // Create bitmap image info from pixel data in current context
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

  // Create a new UIImage object  
  UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

  // Release colorspace, context and bitmap information
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  CGContextRelease(context);
  CFRelease(imageRef);

  // Return the new grayscale image
  return newImage;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use this function but it won't work with images other than 1.0 scale... (breaks on retina)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Monotouch does not bind the `CGRect` functions so not sure how to do this.

When using MonoTouch `CGRect` is mapped to `RectangleF`. A lot of extension methods exists that should map to every function provided by `GCRect`. You should not have any problem in porting ObjectiveC code using them.

If something is missing please fill a bug report @ http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and we'll fix it asap (and provide a workaround when possible).

> There are recipes out there in ObjC but MonoTouch

If you have links then please edit your question and add them. That will make it easier to help you :)

**UPDATE**

Here's a, line-by-line, C# translation of your example. It seems to works for me (and it's much easier to my eyes than Objective-C ;-)

```
    UIImage ConvertToGrayScale (UIImage image)
    {
        RectangleF imageRect = new RectangleF (PointF.Empty, image.Size);
        using (var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceGray ())
        using (var context = new CGBitmapContext (IntPtr.Zero, (int) imageRect.Width, (int) imageRect.Height, 8, 0, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.None)) {
            context.DrawImage (imageRect, image.CGImage);
            using (var imageRef = context.ToImage ())
                return new UIImage (imageRef);
        }
    }
```

Comment: WORKS GREAT!  I think I probably need to spend more time learning to translate the ObjC examples because obviously it can be made to look easy (as you just did).   Thanks

Comment: Glad it works for you :-) Please take the time to accept the answer (green mark below the votes numbers) to allow other people, searching for a similar question, to see an answer is available.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a native port of the blur and tint UIImage categories from WWDC for Monotouch.

- https://github.com/lipka/MonoTouch.UIImageEffects

Sample code for tint and blur:

```
UIColor tintColor = UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha (0.11f, 0.73f);

UIImage yourImage;
yourImage.ApplyBlur (20f /*blurRadius*/, tintColor, 1.8f /*deltaSaturationFactor*/, null);
```

Comment: You should only set the deltaSaturationFactor to 0