# How can I change every color in a UIImage to gray?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, mask

I'm trying to create a mask from an image with a transparent background. I want to create a new UIImage where any pixel that has > 0 alpha to turn gray.

Comment: What part of the process are you having trouble with? Show us the code you've written so far and we can help you better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577567/monotouch-convert-color-uiimage-with-alpha-to-grayscale-and-blur

Comment: I realize the information I provided is sparse, but I don't think that invalidates my question. I have a UIImageView of a present. I want the present to show a gray mask until touched, then the original image is shown. I'm pretty sure the objective is clear. I would provide code but it would simply be setting an image. And the referenced duplicate is concerning MonoTouch, the answer is in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load an image with rendering mode UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate which draws the image as a template image, ignoring its color information.

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

Then set the tintColor of the container to gray

```
yourImageView.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```